# Is it posible to translate a url prefix?

Tags: permalinks

I use a prefix in my url using "add_permastruct" in my functions.php:

```
www.mydomain.com/the_prefix/my_category/postname
```

But I would like to translate "the_prefix". For example, if my site is in english, I will use the prefix "articles" and If my site is in german I will use "artikel".

```
English: www.mydomain.com/en/articles/my_category/postname

German: www.mydomain.com/de/artikel/my_category/postname
```

Any ideas? I use [WPML](http://wpml.org/) plugin

Comment: That functionality is what WPML supposed to be able to do. You should ask their support. Since WPML is a paid plugin with no free versions there is not much chance anybody here can  give you any good answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the following to check for each language and then output the translated permalink structure. For instance:

```
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE==en){
//translate your english the_prefix here
}
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE==de){
//translate your german the_prefix here
}
```

I'm not sure about this, but I would think that you should be able to use the `icl_register_string()` and `icl_t()` functions to register, and output the translated text inside the above if statements. You can find more info about those functions here: [WPML Register Function](http://wpml.org/documentation/support/translation-for-texts-by-other-plugins-and-themes/)

Comment: it is not enough to translate names here, you actually need to change the URL parsing/rewrite rules to have those pages accessible in those URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mark, but... How can I do it?

Comment: Any solution,please?